# In Excel VBA how can I format every other merged cell in a row?

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I have some code that merges 52 columns into the months of a given year.

See Row 5 and 6 below

[image]

My code merges cells that have a common month however for row 6 I would like to format every other merged cell so it is filled black, the font is white and a formula is put into A6 and autofilled right i.e the second merged cell in row 6 under Feb is = pervious cell (under Jan) - 1.

[image]

The code below is provided by user CMArg and almost achieves what I am trying to do...

The result is this

[image]

```
Dim TempRange, TempRange2 As Range
Dim a, c, i, z As Integer

Sub MergeAndPaint()
        z = 60 'the first value in row 6
        a = 1
        For i = 1 To 260 '260 is number of columns up to IZ
            If Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, i).Value <> Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, i + 1).Value Then
                Set TempRange = Range(Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, a), Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, i))
                Set TempRange2 = Range(Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(6, a), Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(6, i))

                With TempRange
                    .Merge
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With

                With TempRange2
                    .Merge
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .Value = z
                    If a Mod 2 = 0 Then
                        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    End If
                End With

                a = i + 1
                z = z - 1
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is confusing me... What is the data structure? I guess the 52 columns correspond to weeks. Where is month declare? In row1? And year?

Comment: My apologies. Yes 52 columns is weeks. Before I run my code it takes the year number and inserts the first monday of the week into column one and then in the next column I reference the first and say = First column + 7 days and drag this right.

Comment: The rows you see above just convert to month so I have Jan jan jan jan jan feb feb feb feb mar mar mar mar in each column as I go right

Comment: My code just searches for values that are the same and merges. To give you the result in my image above

Comment: Excuse, but I'm a newbe, and your code is not merging for me.  Anyway, try `xlPatternSolid` instead of xlSolid (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840282.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will perform what you want to achieve, but is shorter and clearer. See the new EDITED code.

```
    Dim TempRange, TempRange2 As Range
    Dim a, i, z, d As Integer

    Sub MergeAndPaint()
            z = 60 'the first value in row 6
            a = 1 'variable used for setting ranges
            d = 2 'for counting odd and even
            For i = 1 To 260 '260 is number of columns up to IZ
                If Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, i).Value <> Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, i + 1).Value Then
                    Set TempRange = Range(Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, a), Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(5, i))
                    Set TempRange2 = Range(Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(6, a), Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(6, i))

                    With TempRange
                        .Merge
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    End With

                    With TempRange2
                        .Merge
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .Value = z
                        If d Mod 2 = 0 Then
                            .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                            .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                            .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                        End If
                    End With
                    d = d + 1
                    a = i + 1
                    z = z - 1
                End If
            Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much its very close the only thing I cant get is every second cell to by black, see the new image in my question

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @NeverPhased: did you tested it? As per my test it'd not work. In any case you may want to test the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Sub MergeAndPaint2()

Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("MASTER").Rows(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
     .Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=60-counta(R[-1]C1:R[-1]C)+1"
    For i = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
        Call FormatWeek(Range(.Areas(i), .Areas(i + 1).Offset(, -1)).Resize(2))
    Next i
    If .Areas.Count > 1 Then Call FormatWeek(Range(.Areas(i), .Areas(i).Offset(, 3)).Resize(2))
End With

With Worksheets("MASTER").Rows(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(1)
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub


Sub FormatWeek(rng As Range)

With rng
    .Merge (True)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    With .cells(2, 1)
        If .Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
            .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

it works with whatever spacing between month names